# Let's get critical: Jun 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Data Science Stack Exchange](http://datascience.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Question on decision tree in the book Programming Collective Intelligence](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5606/question-on-decision-tree-in-the-book-programming-collective-intelligence)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [K-means: What are some good ways to choose an efficient set of initial centroids?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5656/k-means-what-are-some-good-ways-to-choose-an-efficient-set-of-initial-centroids)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Pandas time series optimization problem: add year](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5529/pandas-time-series-optimization-problem-add-year)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to classify whether text answer is relevant to an initial text question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5601/how-to-classify-whether-text-answer-is-relevant-to-an-initial-text-question)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Abstract data type?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5530/abstract-data-type)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Optimizing Weka for large data sets](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5585/optimizing-weka-for-large-data-sets)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Predictive Model for Customer Payment Pattern](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5492/predictive-model-for-customer-payment-pattern)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Algorithms to find average distance between data maxima](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5548/algorithms-to-find-average-distance-between-data-maxima)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [NoSQL engine/service recommendation for geolocation data](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5693/nosql-engine-service-recommendation-for-geolocation-data)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Classify the coordinate data](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5690/classify-the-coordinate-data)

**Net Score: -7** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 7)

---